# No Connectivity to ESX guests on one server

Tags: networking, vmware-esx

I have a number of ESX servers hosting VM's, all but one of these works ok, however one server  has a problem where any guests on not contactable over the network.

The ESX hosts is contactable, is integrated int VCenter, and you can even live migrate VM's to and from this server, but any VM's on that server are unable to talk to the rest of the network.

The VM's NIC is shown as Up and has the right IP configuration, and as soon as you move it back to another host it works fine.

EDIT

Just to update, I have re-installed ESX on this server, I have also changed the switch it is connected to, with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you compared *all* of the vSwitch/port-group settings between the broken server and a working server? also have you compared their physical switch port configs for differences (in particular native vlanning can sometimes cause odd problems). If these match then I'd either reinstall ESX or, if it might be easier, swap the server boot disks between this bad server and good one, see if the problem moves or stays, if it moves then a reinstall should work/help - if it stays it's a hardware/physical-switch issue. Let us know how you get on.